# Continuous deploy to CloudRun from a container registry

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have an application which is built as a docker container. The users of these applications are different people with their own GCP account. I want to continue to build my applications and release by pushing to a public container registry. I want all my users to automatically pull the latest container image and update their GCP CloudRun service.

In addition, I want to enable the following capabilities

1. Only users who has enabled automatic updates get updates automatically. Others can install them manually or when they enable automatic updates.
2. Ability to deploy to select set of users if they have automatic updates enabled.

(Basically, some custom logic in the continuous deployment workflow to see whether we can do an automatic update or not)

How to achieve this?

GCP documentation shows, I can do continuous deployment if my code in is GitHub and I enable Code build on every change. I want to skip this. Instead, I want all my users to listen to new container images and use them.

Comment: Here it's a custom code that you have to build and to deploy on the developer environment. There is nothing "simple" or "quick".

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I think you missed to share the code. Can you please share?

Comment: I have no code to share, it's a project with code, organisation and best practices.

Comment: How about using `Cloud function` to trigger users based on the changes in container registry? https://cloud.yandex.com/en/docs/functions/concepts/trigger/cr-trigger